# php getting value for html

Tags: php, html

I have the following example:

I have an array of values in config\resources.php - eg.:

```
<?php
    define('resrc', array(
        'logo' => 'src/images/logo.png',
        'bscss' => 'src/bootstrap.css',
        'bsthcss' => 'src/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'bsjs' => 'src/js/bootstrap.js',
        'chset' => 'utf-8',
        'jquery' => '/src/jquery/jquery_1.12.4_min.js',
        )
    );
?>
```

Now in the structure\head.php I have something like this:

```
<?php
require('config/resources.php');
class Head {
    public static $head;
    public static function renderHeadTag() {

        $head = "<head>";
        $head .= "<meta charset=".$resrc['chset'].">";
        $head .= "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">";
        $head .= "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">";

        $head .= "</head>";

        return $head;
    }
}
?>
```

but I still can't get the value of the array. It is quite a while since i were doing something like this. Can anybody give a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using a [constants](http://php.net/constants) array

calling constants must not prefixed with dollar sign

this line :

```
$head .= "<meta charset=".$resrc['chset'].">";
```

should be as follows :

```
$head .= "<meta charset=".resrc['chset'].">";
```

**P.S.** constants following some naming convention , it's better (not must have) to name your constants in capital letters, `RESRC` for example

Comment: Thanks a lot :) looks like it was a long time :P